# Moving an auto rotating 3d polygons in OpenGL with C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, opengl-compat

I'm trying to move these tow auto-rotating polygons to the Right-Left , Up-Down and Front-Back using these keys :
for the pyramid its the keys ('a','w','s','d','+','-')
for the cube its the keys ('←','↑','→','↓','PAGE UP','PAGE DOWN')
the polygons do actually move but they are moving in a weird way not as I wanted them to be moved especially when I try to move them Up-Down and Front-Back
I want to know why they moves like and what should I change to make them moves normal .

this is the code :

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
float pyramid_x = 0, pyramid_y = 0, pyramid_z = 0;
float cube_x = 0, cube_y = 0, cube_z = 0;
float pyramid_angle = 0.0;
float cube_angle = 0.0;
int refresh = 10;//ms 
float degree = 0;
void cube_right(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_x += 0.1;
}
void cube_left(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_x -= 0.1;
}
void cube_up(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_y += 0.1;
}
void cube_down(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_y -= 0.1;
}
void cube_front(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_z -= 0.1;
}
void cube_back(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    cube_z += 0.1;
}
void pyramid_right(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();

    pyramid_x += 0.1;
}
void pyramid_left(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    pyramid_x -= 0.1;
}
void pyramid_up(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    pyramid_y += 0.1;
}
void pyramid_down(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    pyramid_y -= 0.1;
}
void pyramid_front(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    pyramid_z -= 0.1;
}
void pyramid_back(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    pyramid_z += 0.1;
}





void keyboard(int buttons, int x, int y)
{

    switch (buttons)

    {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:cube_left(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:cube_right(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:cube_up(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:cube_down(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:cube_front(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:cube_back(); break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void keyboard(unsigned char buttons, int x, int y)
{
    switch (buttons)
    {
    case 'w':pyramid_front(); break;
    case'a':pyramid_left(); break;
    case's':pyramid_down(); break;
    case'd':pyramid_right(); break;
    case '+':pyramid_front(); break;
    case'-':pyramid_back(); break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void settings()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void drawing_function()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity(); //reset
    glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
    glRotatef(pyramid_angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(pyramid_x, pyramid_y, pyramid_z);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    // front
    glTexCoord3f(1, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // right
    glTexCoord3f(0, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    // back
    glTexCoord3f(0, 1, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    // left
    glTexCoord3f(1, 1, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();


    glLoadIdentity();//(Reset model-view matrix)
    glTranslatef(-2.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
    glRotatef(cube_angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(cube_x, cube_y, cube_z);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //cube

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    pyramid_angle += 1.0f;
    cube_angle -= 0.2f;


}
void timer(int deger)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(refresh, timer, 0);
}

void view_setting(GLsizei x, GLsizei y)
{
    if (y == 0) y = 1; 
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)x / (GLfloat)y;
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50.0f, aspect, 1.0f, 20.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("3d");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawing_function);
    glutReshapeFunc(view_setting);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    settings();
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by "move in a weird way?"

Comment: I apologies for my bad English but I will try my best : 
 when I move them up , down , front and back they start looking like they are moving around the center of the coordinate I don't want them to move like that , what I'm trying to do is to be able to move them while they are rotating around them selves not around the center of the coordinate  edit : if you could try to run the code it will be more clear I think

Comment: If you want the object to rotate around its own center, call `glRotatef` before any `glTranslate`. If you want the object to orbit around another point, call `glTranslate` before `glRotate`. Imagine the object starts out at the origin (0,0,0) then visualize each transformation - rotate, translate, scale - happening in the order you call them in your code. Remember all rotations are relative to the origin, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the transformations. Do the rotation then the translation:

```cpp
glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
glTranslatef(pyramid_x, pyramid_y, pyramid_z);
glRotatef(pyramid_angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

```cpp
glTranslatef(-2.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
glTranslatef(cube_x, cube_y, cube_z);
glRotatef(cube_angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Matrix multiplication is not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). Operations like [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) and [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) setup a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix. Therefore, the transformation that needs to be done first must be the last in code.

---

Further more there is a mistake in `keyboard`. When <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed the the pyramid has to move up rather than to move to the front:

<s>`case 'w':pyramid_front(); break;`</s>

```cpp
case 'w':pyramid_up(); break;
```